# Nesting JSON in Java, Creating JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

Here's the JSON I need, exactly this format:

```
{
  "id":"MESManufacturingTasksDefResp1",
  "type":"MESManufacturingTasksDefResp",
  "attributes":[
    {
      "name":"publisherId",
      "type":"Text",
      "value":"MES"
    },
    {
      "name":"manufacturingFacilityId",
      "type": "Text",
      "value": "warehouse_x"
    },
    {
      "name":"manufacturingTasks",
      "type": "ManufacturingTask",
      

"value":[{"sopDefs":
      {

        "id": "sopId1",
        "name": "sopName1",
        "manufacturingTaskDefs": [
          {
            "id": "rod_cap_extraction",
            "name": "rod_cap_extraction"
          }
        ]
      }

      }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is what I've done so far:

```
static ArrayList<AttDTO> attributes5 = new ArrayList<AttDTO>();

static ArrayList<String> value2 = new ArrayList<String>();

// creating fifth entity
        BaseDTO obj5 = new BaseDTO("MESManufacturingTasksDefResp1","MESManufacturingTasksDefResp", attributes5);
        attributes5.add(new AttDTO("publisherId","Text","MES"));
        attributes5.add(new AttDTO("manufacturingFacilityId","Text","warehouse_x"));
        attributes5.add(new AttDTO("manufacturingTasks","ManufacturingTask", value2 ));
        //value2.add();
        ObjectMapper mapper5 = new ObjectMapper();
        String json5 = mapper5.writeValueAsString(obj5);
        System.out.println("\n" + json5);
```

I have succeded in printing out everything until manufacturingTask as it was required. The element below in this array is impossible to comprehend how to be presented for me is at this time. Any ideas?

> "value":[{"sopDefs":
>
> ```
>   {
>
>     "id": "sopId1",
>     "name": "sopName1",
>     "manufacturingTaskDefs": [
>       {
>         "id": "rod_cap_extraction",
>         "name": "rod_cap_extraction"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method: use `org.JSON`**

`JSONObject` and `JSONArray` libraries are the right choice to solve your problem. You can build an object with `JSONObject.put(key, value)` and build an array with `JSONArray.put(value)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("id", "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp1");
    data.put("type", "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp");
    
    JSONArray attributes = new JSONArray();
    
    JSONObject attribute = new JSONObject();
    attribute.put("name", "publisherId");
    attribute.put("type", "Text");
    attribute.put("value", "MES");
    attributes.put(attribute);
    
    attribute = new JSONObject();
    attribute.put("name", "manufacturingFacilityId");
    attribute.put("type", "Text");
    attribute.put("value", "warehouse_x");
    attributes.put(attribute);
    
    attribute = new JSONObject();
    attribute.put("name", "manufacturingTasks");
    attribute.put("type", "ManufacturingTask");
    
    JSONArray value = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject v = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject sopDefs = new JSONObject();
    sopDefs.put("id","sopId1");
    sopDefs.put("name","sopName1");
    
    JSONArray manufacturingTaskDefs = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject manufacturingTaskDef  = new JSONObject();
    manufacturingTaskDef.put("id", "rod_cap_extraction");
    manufacturingTaskDef.put("name", "rod_cap_extraction");
    manufacturingTaskDefs.put(manufacturingTaskDef);
    
    sopDefs.put("manufacturingTaskDefs",manufacturingTaskDefs);
    v.put("sopDefs", sopDefs);
    value.put(v);
    attribute.put("value", value);
    attributes.put(attribute);
    data.put("attributes", attributes);
    
    System.out.println(data.toString(4));
}
```

The output will be :

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "publisherId",
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "MES"
        },
        {
            "name": "manufacturingFacilityId",
            "type": "Text",
            "value": "warehouse_x"
        },
        {
            "name": "manufacturingTasks",
            "type": "ManufacturingTask",
            "value": [
                {
                    "sopDefs": {
                        "manufacturingTaskDefs": [
                            {
                                "name": "rod_cap_extraction",
                                "id": "rod_cap_extraction"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "sopName1",
                        "id": "sopId1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp1",
    "type": "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp"
}
```

Library source :

1. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json
2. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20220924/json-20220924.jar

---

**Second Method: Use `com.fasterxml.jackson`**

`ObjectNode` and `ArrayNode` libraries also can solve your problem. First, you should define `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()`  as a mapper to create an object and array. You can build an object with `ObjectNode.put(key, value)` or `ObjectNode.set(key, value)` if the value is `ObjectNode` or `ArrayNode` and build an array with `ArrayNode.add(value)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    ObjectNode data = mapper.createObjectNode();
    data.put("id", "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp1");
    data.put("type", "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp");

    ArrayNode attributes = mapper.createArrayNode();

    ObjectNode attribute = mapper.createObjectNode();
    attribute.put("name", "publisherId");
    attribute.put("type", "Text");
    attribute.put("value", "MES");
    attributes.add(attribute);

    attribute = mapper.createObjectNode();
    attribute.put("name", "manufacturingFacilityId");
    attribute.put("type", "Text");
    attribute.put("value", "warehouse_x");
    attributes.add(attribute);

    attribute = mapper.createObjectNode();
    attribute.put("name", "manufacturingTasks");
    attribute.put("type", "ManufacturingTask");

    ArrayNode value = mapper.createArrayNode();
    ObjectNode v = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ObjectNode sopDefs = mapper.createObjectNode();
    sopDefs.put("id", "sopId1");
    sopDefs.put("name", "sopName1");

    ArrayNode manufacturingTaskDefs = mapper.createArrayNode();
    ObjectNode manufacturingTaskDef = mapper.createObjectNode();
    manufacturingTaskDef.put("id", "rod_cap_extraction");
    manufacturingTaskDef.put("name", "rod_cap_extraction");
    manufacturingTaskDefs.add(manufacturingTaskDef);

    sopDefs.set("manufacturingTaskDefs", manufacturingTaskDefs);
    v.set("sopDefs", sopDefs);
    value.add(v);
    attribute.set("value", value);
    attributes.add(attribute);
    data.set("attributes", attributes);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
}
```

The output will be :

```
{
  "id" : "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp1",
  "type" : "MESManufacturingTasksDefResp",
  "attributes" : [ {
    "name" : "publisherId",
    "type" : "Text",
    "value" : "MES"
  }, {
    "name" : "manufacturingFacilityId",
    "type" : "Text",
    "value" : "warehouse_x"
  }, {
    "name" : "manufacturingTasks",
    "type" : "ManufacturingTask",
    "value" : [ {
      "sopDefs" : {
        "id" : "sopId1",
        "name" : "sopName1",
        "manufacturingTaskDefs" : [ {
          "id" : "rod_cap_extraction",
          "name" : "rod_cap_extraction"
        } ]
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

Library source :

1. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core
2. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core

Comment: Is it possible to do this using only Jackson?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please see the updated answer above.